# Retrieving document deleted by pre-commit trigger within transaction

Tags: triggers, marklogic, marklogic-9

We have a pre-commit trigger on document delete event, within an XQuery module associated with trigger we can't retrieve the document contents.

We get document URI but when we do `fn:doc($uri)` it doesn't return document content.

Is there way to get content of deleted doc within the transaction?

Answer (score 2):

If you delete a document **it will not be available in the pre-commit trigger**.

The trigger will see the update made to the document. In this case, it will have already been deleted and will not be available.

## [Pre-Commit Triggers](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/app-dev/triggers#id_34175)

> The module invoked as the result of a pre-commit trigger is evaluated as part of the same transaction that produced the triggering event. It is evaluated by invoking the module on the same App Server in which the triggering transaction is run. It differs from invoking the module with `xdmp:invoke` in one way, however; **the module invoked by the pre-commit trigger sees the updates made to the triggering document.**
>
> **Therefore, pre-commit triggers and the modules from which the triggers are invoked execute in a single context;** if the trigger fails to complete for some reason (if it throws an exception, for example), then the entire transaction, including the triggering transaction, is rolled back to the point before the transaction began its evaluation.

You haven't described what you are trying to achieve, or how the deletes are being performed. It sounds like you really need a pre-delete action, not a pre-commit. There may be other ways to achieve the desired result.

For example, you might consider using a custom function to perform the deletes.

- You could move the logic out of the pre-commit trigger and into that custom function to avoid using triggers altogether.
- Or the custom function could perform a "soft delete" in order to mark it as deleted and otherwise unavailable (i.e. adjust permissions) and then allow the pre-commit trigger to perform the `xdmp:document-delete()`.